# How to utilise data from another package as parameter in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

For my rmarkdown I wish to be able to parameterise data from the palmerpenguins package. However I am unable to utilise it when I specify it as a parameter and go to knit my file. `params$data` only prints out the word penguins when I want it to print out the whole data table, and `params$data$species` fails. Attached below is also the error code produced. Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

````
---
title: "Project_Report"
author: "Caitlin Luo"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: pdf_document
params:
  data: !r penguins
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerspenguins)
```

```{r penguins}
params$data
params$data$species
```
````

[image: error produces]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is from another package you have to use the `package::function` notation in the YAML.
e.g.

```
---
title: "Project_Report"
author: "Caitlin Luo"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: pdf_document
params:
  data: !r palmerpenguins::penguins
---
```